# Does the cache for fetch need to be managed by the client?

Tags: javascript, caching, fetch-api

When fetching data with a [polyfilled](https://github.com/github/fetch) fetch, I'm getting a 304 response as described [here](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/288). Fetch apparently automatically generates the appropriate `If-None-Match` header for my request, and my backend replies with a 304 (data is already in cache). The request isn't properly fullfilled though.

I couldn't find any documentation on where this cached data can be found though. So should the cached data be retrieved automatically? I could set a `'cache-control': 'no-cache'` header, but I'd prefer to use caching of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, if the server returns a 304 for the request that the browser sent to it, then the browser fulfills the request from it's cache (depends on the browser) just as it does for any normal HTTP Request or XMLHTTP Request.

If however you do not want to get content from the cache, and you want to force a brand new load of content, you will want to set the applicable `'cache-control': 'no-cache'` header AND ensure that the URL you are trying to fetch is unique (either by path or parameters).  Often the easiest way to do this is append a dummy param with the current timestamp. e.g. `...&_=1483970310923`

Comment: Ok good. So this isn't something the app itself needs to manage.